# Looping difficulty in non-activity class

Tags: java, android

I've created a class for a quiz where each question will be its own object as `ReviewLogic`.

In my activity when I create `ReviewLogic0` followed by `ReviewLogic1`, the activity loads everything in `ReviewLogic1`.

Reviewing the class, I think I need a loop to keep cycling through the class until the question has been successfully answered, then terminate to allow loading the next object correctly.

My problem is that I am not sure where and how to apply this loop.

I've attempted using a `while` loop with the thought of `while (!questionAnswered) { if... else... }` however that's giving me an endless loop and crash.

The logic is fairly simple: there are 4 of these

```
    answer3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            answer0.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.unselectedbutton);
            answer1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.unselectedbutton);
            answer2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.unselectedbutton);
            answer3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selectedbutton);
            answerSelect = 3;
        }
    });
```

and the actual logic component

```
    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                if (answerSelect == correctAnswer) {
                    makeToast(context, "Correct!");

                } else {
                    makeToast(context, "Try again.");
                }

        }
    });
```

Activity class

```
 ReviewLogic question1 = new ReviewLogic(1, textReviewBody,"Question 1 place holder",
            textTitle,btnReview0,
            btnReview1,btnReview2, btnReview3, btnReviewSubmit,
            btnReviewContinue, GetStarted.this);
    question1.setVisibilityAll();
    question1.setAnswer0("0");
    question1.setAnswer1("1");
    question1.setAnswer2("2");
    question1.setAnswer3("3");

    ReviewLogic question2 = new ReviewLogic(1,textReviewBody,"Question 2 loading early.",
            textTitle,btnReview0,
            btnReview1,btnReview2, btnReview3, btnReviewSubmit,
            btnReviewContinue, GetStarted.this);
    question2.setVisibilityTwo();
    question2.setAnswer0("ans 1");
    question2.setAnswer1("ans 2");
}
```

Where (and what type) is the best place to start the loop so that the activity does not just automatically load the next object in line?

Thanks

Comment: Downvotes are fine if you feel the post justifies it, but at least post some rationale so I can correct the post please.

Comment: Please explain better the problem and post complete activity source code otherwise we can help you

Comment: Just load your next question when the previous one got answered in your btnSubmit listener. No loop required.

Comment: Activity class loaded in

Answer (score 0):

If you have a ViewPager with serveral instances of a fragment that has the object of your questions, than you can just handle the click in one of the answers, after that just call the next fragment. This way you dont need to use loop. You can achieve this same effect calling other activities instead of fragments in a ViewPager